# How to update tables with many-to-many relationship when performing crud operations in Spring Boot

Tags: database, spring-boot, controller, many-to-many, crud

I'm trying to create a Spring Boot backend for my project. In the database I have `Deck` and `Word` tables with a many-to-many relationship connected via `DeckWord` table. The bridge table has additional fields and a composite PK consisting of the other 2 tables' PK's.

I am not sure about how I should structure the crud operations in my project. Say I'm trying to add a new word and it should be assigned to a certain deck. What model's controller should handle the `post` operation in that scenario: `Word` or `DeckWord`? Should the `Deck`'s `List<DeckWord>` be updated as well?

**UPDATE**:

Included the models, omitted the getters, setters and constructors

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "deck")

    public class Deck {
        @Id
        @SequenceGenerator(
                name = "deck_sequence",
                sequenceName = "deck_sequence",
                allocationSize = 1
        )
        @GeneratedValue(
                strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
                generator = "deck_sequence"
        )
        @Column(name = "deck_id")
        private Long id;
        @Transient
        private Boolean learnt;
        private String name;
    
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "deck", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<DeckWord> deckwords;
    
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="appuser_id",referencedColumnName="appuser_id")
        private Appuser appuser;
    }
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "word")

    public class Word {
        @Id
        @SequenceGenerator(
                name = "word_sequence",
                sequenceName = "word_sequence",
                allocationSize = 1
        )
        @GeneratedValue(
                strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
                generator = "word_sequence"
        )
        @Column(name = "word_id")
        private Long id;
        private String definition;
        private String transcription;
    
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "word", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<DeckWord> deckwords;
    }
```

and the bridge table:

```
@Embeddable
class DeckWordKey implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "deck_id")
    Long deckId;

    @Column(name = "word_id")
    Long wordId;
}


@Entity
@Table
public class DeckWord {
    @EmbeddedId
    DeckWordKey id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("deckId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "deck_id",referencedColumnName="deck_id")
    Deck deck;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("wordId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "word_id",referencedColumnName="word_id")
    Word word;

    private Boolean learnt;
    private LocalDate last_checked;
    private WordGroup wordGroup;
}
```

Comment: Do the `Post` live on their own or always need to be associated with a `User`? Additionally, can you please add your entities' code? Thanks!

Comment: Hi I updated the question and the model names. In  this db a Word should always be assigned to a Deck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your questions:

**What model's controller should handle the post operation in that scenario: Word or DeckWord?**

Given that a `Word` should always be assigned to a `Deck`, then I would use a POST request to the URL "/decks/{deckId}/words" to create a new `Word`. The request body should include `definition` and `transcription`.

**Should the Deck's List be updated as well?**

Yes, it must. For that, you need to use `deckId` that you receive as a path parameter.